# Get ViewPager scroll position if it isn't touched

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I would like to know if there is a way to get the ViewPager child scroll position but when the user doesn't scroll it phisically. 
I mean, when the user scrolls the viewpager, you can get the scroll position using the OnPageScrolled method inside the OnPageChangeListener, but if the user doesn't swipe from the start of the pager to the end of it, it will only return the scroll position while the user is touching it, so if he only swipes to the middle of the viewpager, sufficient for the viewpager to change the page automatically, while it scrolls automatically it doesn't return the scroll position.
I don't know if I explaned it well... I hope :p

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found the solution! It was my error, I'm sorry :p

I had the code that gave me the positionOffset (the position of the page when it is scrolling) inside an if() that made the code only work when the user was phisically dragging the viewpager.

Answer (score 0):

First get the position of the active view in the pager, then use getChildAt(index) to get that view and the you can get the scroll position whit getScrollY()

The code should be:

```
view_pager.getChildAt(view_pager.getCurrentItem()).getScrollY())
```